# WP "mixed content" в gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https, gutenberg

При сохранении поста получаю:

> Ошибка обновления. Возможно, что подключение к сети недоступно.

В консоли вижу ошибку "**Mixed Content**": https://pastenow.ru/9C9QK
Если отключить gutenberg, то сохраняет без проблем.
В настройках сайт урл указан с https, плагины типа "Really Simple SSL" не помогают.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в как исправить данную ошибку?

Answer (score 0):

Заменил `.htaccess` на стандартный вордпрессовский и все заработало.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```